# Wrong package dependency - ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting the wrong version of Entity Framework pulled under ASP.Net Core 2.1.101 when setting the dependency to a wildcard (*).

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This pulls EntityFramework 1.2.3 and not the latest (6.2.0).

Is this a NuGet issue?

Comment: 1. You can't use ASP.NET Core 2.1 on netstandard2.0. 2. You can't use EF 6.x .net core, since it requires full framework, 3. to target .net core you need to use `netcoreapp2.0` target, `netstandard2.0` is for libraries 4. If you are looking for EF Core, it's package name is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and up until 2.0 (not sure for 2.1) its tied to the appropriate `netstandardx.y` / `netcoreappx.y` target (means: EF core needs netstandard2.0/netcoreapp2.0 at least

Comment: So please clearify your question on what exactly you want to use and which platforms to target? windows only? Linux? Mac? EF Core or EF legacy (.net framework only) and what your reasons are to try out the preview versions